# how to access object's member through a method which filled by another method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know the title is a little bit confusion, here is the details:

Say I have a custom object defined in javascript, and there is a public member defined in it:

```
 function Test()
 {
   this.testArray = [];
 }
```

And I have two methods for this object, one is read out some xml file and filled into the array:

```
 Test.prototype.readXML = function()
 {
   var self = this;
   $.get('assest/xml/mydata.xml', function(d){
    $(d).find("item").each(function(){
            var item = new Item;
            item.ID = ($(this).attr("ID"));
            item.body = ($(this).find("body").text());
            });
     self.testArray.push(item);
   });
   }
```

And another function, which will display the content into the HTML page.

```
  Test.prototype.appendInfo = function()
  {
     var i;
     for (i=0; i<testArray.length;i++)
     {
       $('#testdisplay').append(testArray[i].ID +"<br />");
       $('#testdisplay').append(testArray[i].body = "<br /");
      }
   }
```

However, the display function continue gives me error that the testArray is not defined. I'm not sure where is the problem, since I put the display function behind the reading function. I expect that the data will be stored in the array and could be accessed anytime I need them.

Hope some one will kindly help me about this! Thank you!
         }
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I notice two problems with your code.

First when you do your ajax call you need to pass a deferred back to the user. Since ajax calls are async it may not finish right away.

So your readXML function should do this. It should return the jquery get.

```
Test.prototype.readXML = function() {
   var self = this;
   return $.get('assest/xml/mydata.xml', function(d){
        $(d).find("item").each(function(){
            var item = new Item;
            item.ID = ($(this).attr("ID"));
            item.body = ($(this).find("body").text());
        });
        self.testArray.push(item);
   });
}
```

Next you your second function append was just missing some context.

```
Test.prototype.appendInfo = function() {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<this.testArray.length;i++) {
       $('#testdisplay').append(this.testArray[i].ID +"<br />");
       $('#testdisplay').append(this.testArray[i].body = "<br /");
    }
}
```

So your code should look like this.

```
var mytest = new Test();

mytest.readXML().done(function(){
    mytest.appendInfo();
}).fail(function(){
    // put some fallback code here
});
```

Updated:
Added additional this's.

Comment: You missed a few more `this`s

Comment: Thank you @arhea. Your methods worked! However I still have little confused. Is this solution means that if I want using ajax's functionality, I have to called any methods which need access the data read and stored by this ajax transfer INSIDE the ajax function call? Just like you showed me in the last block of the code. Is there a way, to let the program finished reading, than doing other job and treat the storage variable as a normal local static variable?

Comment: No ajax calls are async. Javascript will keep going. That is why all code that needs to wait for the ajax call to complete needs to be inside a callback. I encourage you to read all about jQuery Deferreds

Answer (score 0):

There is no `testArray` in your `appendInfo()` function, that's why it says it's not defined. You should use `this.testArray` instead.

Every time you want to use a variable *declared inside your scope*, but *outside the function* you are using, you must use `this.yourVariable`