# how to store value read from XML to a local object's members using .get() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I think this is another trick variable scope and ajax problem in jQuery and javascript I have met.

Say I have an object:

```
Container = function()
{
//CSS Style Paramaters:
    this.width = "";
    this.height = "";
    this.margin = "";
    this.margin_option = "";
    this.position = ""; 
}
```

And I have a method of this object which should read some xml data from an xml file and store them into this object's members:

```
Container.prototype.readXML4Container =function()
{
            var self = this;
        $.get("assest/xml/layout.xml",function(xml)
        {
                  $(xml).find("body").each(function(){
                     self.width = ($(this).find("width").text());
                     self.height = ($(this).find("height").text());
                     self.margin = ($(this).find("margin").text());
                     //And more code like this.
        });
       });
}
```

After this function, there is another function needs to call it, and apply CSS data by using .css()

```
Container.prototype.applyCSS = function()
{
    this.readXML4Container();

    $("#container").css({
        'width':this.width,
        'height':this.height,
        'position':this.position,
        'margin': this.margin
    });

}
```

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<root>
<body>
    <margin>0</margin>
    <padding>0</padding>
    <font-family>Trebuchet MS, sans-serif</font-family>
    <color>#666</color>
</body> 
<container>
    <width>1220px</width>
    <height>730px</height>
    <margin>0 auto</margin>
    <position>relative</position>
    <font-size>1.0em</font-size>
    <font-color>blue</font-color>
</container>


<Menubar>
    <width>660px</width>
    <height>58px</height>
    <position>absolute</position>
    <left>275px</left>  
</Menubar>

<Mainsection>
    <width>664px</width>
    <height>660px</height>
    <position>absolute</position>
    <position-left>270px</position-left>
    <position-top>60px</position-top>   
</Mainsection>
</root>
```

My problem is, it seems that the value has never been stored into the members variables. When I created an instance of that object, and call both of the function, the CSS style is never applied into the DOM in the HTML.

However, if I do not read XML file but just give some value at the beginning, it works fine. So I know that my applyCSS part should be good. The problem should be at reading and store phase.

I am trying to solve this problem for more than a day....Can any one help me about this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's see. You have about 3 problems.

1)  `self.margin = ($(this).find("margin).text());`

You're missing a closing double quote around margin

2) Your XML isn't valid: `<position-left>275px</left>`

3) Finally the big one: Remember, you're using AJAX. Don't forget what the A stands for :). Your function does this:

```
    this.readXML4Container();

        $("#container").css({
            'width':this.width,
            'height':this.height,
            'position':this.position,
            'margin': this.margin
        });

But readXML4Container is ASYNCHRONOUS. So you call your readXML method and then immediately try to apply the CSS, but the css hasn't been loaded yet from the server.
```

You should really just have one function like this:

```
 Container.prototype.readXML4Container =function()
        {
            var self = this;
            $.get("XMLFile1.xml",function(xml)
            {                
                $(xml).find("body").each(function () {

                    self.width = ($(this).find("width").text());
                    self.height = ($(this).find("height").text());
                    self.margin = ($(this).find("margin").text());
                });

                $("#container").css({
                    'width': self.width,
                    'height': self.height,
                    'position': self.position
                });
            });
        }
```

Of course, you have other problems, like why do you have TWO body tags? Only the last one will apply. And then of course, your body XML doesn't even "HAVE" properties for width and height...

Comment: Thank you @aquinas for the detail reply! However the code is still not working in your ways...I put an alert statement just after the each()function line, but the strange thing is there is no alert on the web! Seems it stop after the get has been executed...

Comment: Oh, and I fixed the typing error you have pointed out! Thank you!

Comment: Did you change the URL? :) I changed mine to be XMLFile1.xml. You had: assest/xml/layout.xml

Comment: Hi @aquinas, thank your for your patient answers:) I notice that the different in your code you have show me at above link is that rather using .get, you are using .post. Is that the key to the problem?

Comment: No, that's not the problem. You have a JS error someplace. Are you using a debugger?

Comment: yes I do using the debugger. However it not reports any error...And one strange things is if i put some alert() inside of the each() function ,it will not be executed...T_T. I am totally confused now. I have asked a similar questions about this however it is an different approach, which that time I need to handle a whole object but not some sigle variables. That question is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146680/how-to-access-objects-member-through-a-method-which-filled-by-another-method

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem a few times. I usually design Javascript classes slightly differently, and have never experienced scoping issues with this method.

The below example does what you're wanting (with some dummy data, in a dummy Ajax request and loop to cater for scope issues). It also creates two objects with randomised data to test that they're not being stored statically in the prototype. Timeout is to ensure that the Ajax request has completed before outputting data. http://jsfiddle.net/wERTp/16/

```
var Container = function()
{
};

Container.prototype = {    
    width: '',
    height: '',
    margin: '',
    margin_option: '',
    position: '',

    readXML4Container: function()
    {
        $.get("", this.saveValues.bind(this));
    },

    saveValues: function(xml) {
        var self = this;
        var values = [{
            width: 10 + Math.random(),
            height: 10 + Math.random(),
            margin: 10 + Math.random(),
            margin_option: '',
            position: 'relative'
        }];
        $.each(values, function() {
            self.width = this.width;
            self.height = this.height;
            self.margin = this.margin;
            self.margin_option = this.margin_option;
            self.position = this.position;
        });
    },

    outputValues: function() {
        console.log(this.width, this.height, this.margin, this.margin_option, this.position);
    }
}

var container = new Container();
container.readXML4Container();
setTimeout(function() {
    container.outputValues();
}, 1000);

var container2 = new Container();
container2.readXML4Container();
setTimeout(function() {
    container2.outputValues();
}, 1000);​
```